# What is the value of x in: $(20-2x)(20-2x)x = 576$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the step to find the value of x in this equation?
$$(20-2x)(20-2x)x = 576$$

I am doing Shaum's pre-calculus and there is this a word problem at the end of the chapter. There is 3 side of a box and the volume, and you have to find the value of x. I tried putting all the terms on one side and do a synthetic division to find x but it didn't work. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: From an easy guess, $x=4$. I just divided both sides by $4$, then noticed the right side is just $12^2=6^2\cdot4$. By dividing the cubic by $x-4$, I found the other two roots to be $8\pm2\sqrt7$.

Comment: yes, 4 is one of the answer. The other answer is $8 - \sqrt{28}$ How would they arrive to that answer tho? Like I just cannot figure out what are the step to solve this.

Comment: Did you ... read the comment?

Comment: Ah sorry, i did not see the full answer :)

Comment: Brilliant, I get it now. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the equation can be factorized as

$$(20-2x)(20-2x)x -576$$
$$= 4(x^3-20x^2+100x -144)$$
$$= 4(x^3-20x^2+64x + 36x -144)$$
$$= 4[x(x-16)(x-4)+36(x -4)]$$
$$= 4(x-4)(x^2-16x+36)=0$$

which yields the solutions $x=4, \>8\pm 2\sqrt7$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(20-2x)^2 x=24^2$

Since the LHS is equal to a square, it has to be a square itself, which means x could  be a square because the product of 2 squares is a square.

i.e. $m^2 *n$ is a square if n is a square.

Trying out a few values of x will fetch the answer,

$x=2^2=4$

and then do the long division to get the other two roots.

Comment: However, the problems never says that $x$ must be an integer so there could be noninteger solutions. All we know is that $0<x<10$ so that none of the edge lengths are nonpositive. In fact, plugging (20−2x)(20−2x)x = 576 into Wolfram Alpha gives $8\pm2\sqrt{7}$ as solutions as well, but $8+2\sqrt{7}$ is larger than $10$ so $8-2\sqrt{7}$ is the only other solution.

Comment: Yes. This is only a guess-and-check method which helps in narrowing down the integer roots(if any).